# Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app in production with apache2 and passenger. But some of my images didn't appeared so i changed the path inside the 'image_tag' like this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/assets/#{product.image_url}", {:title => "Push it into cart!"}), line_items_path(product_id: product), method: :post %>
```

After this all work fine in production. But when i try in development, i got this error:

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AbsoluteAssetPathError in Store#index 
Asset names passed to helpers should not include the "/assets/" prefix. Instead of "/assets/cs.jpg", use "cs.jpg"
```

What i should do to make it work in both enviroments?

Comment: Did you set `config.assets.prefix` to something else than the default `/assets`?

Comment: @BrunoE. No i haven't something like this in development. rb or in production.rb.

Comment: Usually you shouldn't need /assets/ in the call to image_tag. Can you post how the image url looked like in production that didn't work?

Comment: When i select 'viewpage info' in my browser, i see that it looks for the images in http://depot.local/images/cs.jpg and not in  assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`image_tag` works without using `/assets/` path as long as you have the asset pipeline enabled (which is the default) and your image is in `app/assets/images/` folder. If your image is outside that folder it won't get precompiled so you'll have to add it to the asset precompilation, in your `config/environments/production.rb` add

```
config.assets.precompile += ['image.jpg']
```

I think  that for your problem you shouldn't store the images of your products in the `assets` folder as this is used for the application images  not for you content (models) images, those should be stored in the public folder `public/uploads` is commonly used for that by gems like `paperclip`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The images are in `app/assets/images`. I will try `paperclip` thanks for advise.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use /assets/ prefix, it's possible that you just need to precompile assets for production.

> rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

It also depends on where are you using the said asset, for example, when using it in stylesheet you should use image-url('image.jpg') rails css helper. When using it inline in the view, you use the image_tag helper, as you have.

Comment: @3mpretri  I have done it ,it doesn't work. I can see the other images except the images from the code in my main post.

Comment: Try one more thing @Gregory_ynwa, add to string method on your product image path like so --> #{product.image_url.to_s}